# c# linq xml where clause XAttribute with XName can be null

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, nullable-reference-types

Net Core Mvc 6 App.

I reading an XML using Linq.

The XML es like this

```
<taglines common-copyright="©2007 ">
    <tagline brandID="1" brandName="BCBS" >
        <registered registered="®Registered">
        </registered>
        <copyright copyright="©2007">
        </copyright>
        <tagline2 tagline2="Data.">
        </tagline2>
    </tagline>
</taglines>
```

The linq is like this

```
 XmlDocument xmlDocument = new();
 XElement element = XElement.Load(String.Concat(_environment.WebRootPath, "/img/TagLines.xml"));
   
 var query = from XElement r in element.Descendants("tagline")
             where r.Attribute("brandID").Value == siteId
             select r.Element("tagline2")?.Attribute("tagline2");

 var aa = query.FirstOrDefault();
 if (aa != null)
    footer = aa.Value;
```

It works fine, the problem I am facing is that I have a warning in line

```
r.Attribute("brandID").Value
```

Saying that `An XAttribute that has the specific XName: null if there is no attribute with that specific name`

So I have to check if XName `"brandID"` exists...

How can I avoid that warning?

Thanks

Comment: Do not use Value which give exception.  Instead cast : where (string)r.Attribute("brandID") == siteId You can also cast to int.

Comment: HI I replace it.. I add (string)r.Attribute("brandID")  but have the same warning..
"Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type"
Thanks

Comment: solved..
(string?)r.Attribute("brandID")